# Regex to allow space in words if only there are quotes in the string - Java

Tags: java, regex

So I came up with a regex to match words between single quotes and back quotes and in the format `a.b[.c] =d.e[.f] (followed by anything)`, where the words can be surrounded by quotes :

Eg :

```
dqwdasasd.'asd' =\`sadadwdadaasda\`.\`wgfgdf\
```

Regex :

```
^((\`|')?(\w|_)+\2)(\.(\`|')?(\w|_)+\5){1,2} *= *((\`|')?(\w|_)+\8)(\.(\`|')?(\w|_)+\11){1,2}[ .]*
```

But now I want to modify the same to allow spaces in between the words if only the single quotes or backquotes are present.

```
dqwdasasd.'a sd' =\`sada dwdadaa sda\`.\`wgf  gdf\`
```

I tried using back reference but failed to understand how to do it. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Do you really need/want to use regex for this?  For detecting quoted content, I think a rudimentary parser might be a better long term bet.

Comment: `(\w|_)` can simplified in `\w` alone as it already includes `_`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will consider that.

Comment: @Toto Oh, Thank you, I am new to regex, I did not read through properly I guess